# remote_api_stub not working

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm following Google's documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi#using_the_remote_api_in_a_local_client) for using `remote_api_stub`.

This works fine from a command line:

```
remote_api_shell.py -s opavote.appspot.com
```

But if I run the following in a Python shell:

```
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine")
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib")
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2")
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5")
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy")
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/concurrent")
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/docker")
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/requests")
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/websocket")
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib")
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/antlr3")

from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

def auth_func():
  return (raw_input('Username:'), getpass.getpass('Password:'))

remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApi(None, '/remote_api', auth_func, "opavote.appspot.com")
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApi(None, '/remote_api', auth_func, "opavote.appspot.com")
  File "/Users/joneill/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 874, in ConfigureRemoteApi
    app_id = GetRemoteAppIdFromServer(server, path, rtok)
  File "/Users/joneill/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 569, in GetRemoteAppIdFromServer
    response = server.Send(path, payload=None, **urlargs)
  File "/Users/joneill/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 427, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: Found
```

I've done the patch [here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12123) for urllib2.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you had a look at what a 302 means and tried to interpret what that implies ?

Comment: @TimHoffman, yes, I know what a 302 error is but it does not give me any insight as to how I should change the Google provided example.  If I understand correctly, Google writes the handler for these calls so it is all opaque to me.  I also read that other people were having similar issues with federated login but I am not using federated login.

Comment: Where does the 302 send you then? You could probably check from there. if it sends you to a login page, then it's possible your error is because of authentication (for instance)

Comment: @Patrice, I'm just calling a Google function, and this Google function raises an exception because when it does a urllib2 call (details unknown to me) it gets an unexpected 302 status code.  How am I supposed to figure out where the 302 goes?  It is super frustrating that Google provided examples don't work.

Comment: @TimHoffman and Patrice, please let me know if I am being dense.  My login credentials work (e.g., with remote_api_shell.py).  I don't know how I am supposed to debug Google's code.

Comment: @Kekito normally a 302 response has the location of the redirect in its location header. You would need to investigate that. Since the call is made in the shell, you might need to open your network tab and check there